# Spring cloud gateway - Lookup configuration basis request parameter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

Is there any in-built functionality in Spring cloud gateway to look up configuration (either the local YAML file or spring cloud config server) basis a value passed in request header/parameter/path without having to write custom logic?

For eg: say request has a header param named "clientid", I need to be able look up configuration basis key=clientid to get value "clientsecret" and then pass it downstream.

Regards
Jacob